# Retrieve docker image ID

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to retrieve the docker image ID through the [API](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/registry/spec/api/). Using following URL:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mesosphere/marathon/tags/v0.11.1/

I am getting this result back:

> {"name": "v0.11.1", "full_size": 536893184, "id": 1118232, "repository": 60768, "creator": 372823, "last_updater": 77974, "last_updated": "2015-11-04T16:30:33.343998Z", **"image_id": null**, "v2": true}

The desired `image_id` tag is null, but it should be a 12 char string. How do I get it?